# How to construct a 4 input AC AND logic gate?

Tags: pcb-design, ac, signal-processing

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2mv6K.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have four different safety switches connected to four different devices. If one of those safety switches trip then I want a signal to know. I want the other three devices to continue operating.

After reading the comments I made the schematic that should be shown above, and edited the above text. Now my question is whether I have to construct a logic gate like this or if AC input gates exist. I have started looking at digikey and mouser, but am not having much luck.

Below is some of the stuff I wrote before.

Below is a photo of a schematic I know will not currently work, because LTV-844 wants a DC output.

Here is the schematic of the LTV-844: https://optoelectronics.liteon.com/upload/download/DS-70-96-0013/LTV-8X4%20series%20201509.pdf

Finally I should stress that the symbol in the schematic is not the LTV-844 it is one that is similar to it and was already in KiCad libraries. The LTV-844 would have two LEDs at each input is the only difference.

Am I overthinking this? Is there a better way to do what I am wanting to do?

[image: Schematic of board]

Comment: You aren't making a truth table with don't care states You have 4 inputs and 4+1 outputs, 1 logic level being if any are off, but Pwr out is not being showed with any logic controls. Everything else is irrelevant until you have a logic spec with I/O interface specs and tolerances. But if there is no logic for if 2 fail or 3 fail, then your cct. is just a NAND logic interface

Comment: I have no idea what "continue to receive and transmit power" means. Your diagram suggests that you want the load to be on only if **all** the switches are on, and off otherwise. For that, just wire them in series. This is the logical equivalent of an AND gate. If you want something else, try to describe it more clearly.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The wires going into input side of the optocoupler are connected to a separate device. A safety switch is on each of those devices and will cut the power to that device if it trips. The output end is going to an LED board to turn on an LED (separate PCB that takes AC input), and I want that light to go off if one switch is turned off. Our current option is to wire it in series but then if one switch trips all devices turn off. I will try to edit my question to explain it better.

Comment: Your schematic shows the switches shorting the power source - that can't be right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution has many components but is very energy efficient.

[image: 4 channel AC voltage monitor]

1. R01-R04 and R09 limit AC peak currents, fusible versions recommended
2. C05-C09 form AC current sources of around 5mA
3. Two diodes each form rectifiers
4. C01-C04 and C10 deliver current during the other half wave
5. The series connection of OC01-OC04 finally is the "AC-AND-Gate"

The input capacitors are big, but there is (nearly) no heat dissipation. Bare resistors would dissipate 1W per channel. I prefere the cap's in an "always on" circuit.

Please be careful, nothing can be touched here while connected.

Comment: Thank you for this. I do have a couple of questions. One is perhaps to clarify that the indicator light we are connecting to is on a PCB previously made (not by me) that takes AC input then rectifies it, so given that the diodes and capacitors shown on the output end are not necessary I think. Second is a question about the capacitors I am guessing they are there because it is a half wave rectifier and the capacitor discharging will keep the optocoupler or relay on through the whole wave? Again thank you. I will likely accept this answer once I test it.

Comment: @KodyRogers: Yes and yes to your questions

Answer (score 0):

Here's how.

[image]

The relay contacts K1, K2, K3 & K4, in series, serve as the 4 - input AC 'AND' gate that energises the indicator lamp.

When no safety switch is tripped, all the relays are actuated and the four devices energised. The indicator lamp is also lit.

When a safety switch trips, the corresponding relay and device are de-energised and the indicator lamp goes off.

However, the other three devices remain energised.